# jQuery Form Validator plugin require value to be one of the suggested values

Tags: jquery

I have a form that uses jQuery Form Validator plugin from [www.formvalidator.net](http://www.formvalidator.net) (version 2.3.26) with a field name `street`. The `data-suggestion` is filled with street names from a json data set using below code:

```js
$(function() {
  $.validate();
});

var streets = ["ABACOWEG", "ABATTOIRWEG", "ADMIRAALSWEG"];

if ($("input[name='street']").length) {
  var array = [];
  streets.forEach(function(name) {
    array.push(name);
  });
  $.formUtils.suggest($("input[name='street']"), array);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.79/jquery.form-validator.min.js" integrity="sha256-H7bYoAw738qgns17P+7wWt77AfnEh7yCJMQGUCNcxQA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input id="field_1851" class="form-control" type="text" name="street" value="" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min5" data-suggestions="">
```

```
$(function() {
    $.validate();
});

var streets = var streets = ["ABACOWEG","ABATTOIRWEG","ADMIRAALSWEG",.......];

if($("input[name='street']").length) {
   var array = [];
   streets.forEach(function(name) {
       array.push(name);
   });
   $.formUtils.suggest($("input[name='street']"), array);
 }
```

The form field is as follows:

```
<input id="field_1851" class="form-control" type="text" name="street" value="" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min5" data-suggestions="">
```

The suggestion works fine, but would like the validator to check if a street name from the suggestion has been selected. So the user cannot add his/her own street name when it's not in the list.

Cannot seem to find this in the documentation, so any help will be much appreciated.

PS. I know I can create an ajax method that does this check, but am mainly wondering if this is possible within the same validator script

Comment: what is `streets`, there may be some optimizations there.

Comment: Can you please provide all code

Comment: If you can provide more evidence this is not a duplicate we can vote to reopen

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, What duplicate? I cannot find it here on StackOverflow...
I have added the streets array in the code. But like said in the question, the suggestion works fine. I just want to know if it's possible to validate the value the user has entered is in the streets array. So let's say a user does not select one of the suggestions and just types in a street name that is not in the suggestion list, then it shouldn't validate

Comment: note that when I voted to close as duplicate it put that in the question for us.  Your note reinforces the thought that it is a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, please undo the duplicate marking please as this is a different plugin

Comment: Please provide link(s) to the plugin you are using and the documentation (site?) for this, otherwise you do not have enough information for anyone to answer this properly here.  Be sure to include version information as this may change over time and we want to keep it contextually accurate.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, thanks for removing the duplicate. I had already added the link and now also the version number

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (I threw this together really fast so you might be able to enhance it)

```js
var streets = ["ABACOWEG", "ABATTOIRWEG", "ADMIRAALSWEG"];
$(function() {
  $.formUtils.suggest($("input[name='street'][type='text']"), streets);

  // Add custom validation rule
  $.formUtils.addValidator({
    name: 'fromstreets',
    validatorFunction: function(value, $el, config, language, $form) {
      let isIncluded = streets.includes(value);
      if (!isIncluded) {
        if ($("#updatestreets").is(":checked")) {
          console.log("ready to update");
          $el.trigger("update-street");
          return !isIncluded;
        }
      }
      return isIncluded;
    },
    errorMessage: 'You have to answer with a street',
    errorMessageKey: 'badStreet'
  });

  let vstreet = $("input[name='street'][type='text']");
  vstreet.on('beforeValidation', function(value, lang, config) {
      
      console.log('before',streets );
    })
    .on('update-street', function(event) {
      let v = $(this).val();
      console.log('adding:', v, event.type);
      if (!streets.includes(v)) {
        console.log('not in there yet');
        streets.push(v);
        $.formUtils.suggest($("input[name='street']"), streets);
        $(this).validate();
      }
    });
  $('#myform').on('submit', function() {
    return false;
  });
  $.validate();
  vstreet.val("CherryPie");
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/theme-default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.79/jquery.form-validator.min.js" integrity="sha256-H7bYoAw738qgns17P+7wWt77AfnEh7yCJMQGUCNcxQA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="myform">
  update Street: <input type="checkbox" id='updatestreets' value="1" />
  <input id="field_1851" class="form-control" type="text" name="street" value="" data-validation="fromstreets" data-validation-length="min5" data-suggestions="" />
</form>
```